# How can I convert the facebook post created_time to the time zone of the user?

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am displaying Facebook posts in my Android application using the Facebook SDK. I have the created_time for each post in the format:

```
2012-01-04T12:28:52+0000
```

I was able to parse this into a Java Date object like so:

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+SSSS";
public static Date parseDate(String str) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse(str);
    } catch(ParseException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to parse date string \"" + str + "\"");
    }
    return date;
  }
```

Then, I am attempting to display a message describing the time that has elapsed since the post was created using this method:

```
public static String timeAgoInWords(Date from) {
    Date now = new Date();
    long difference = now.getTime() - from.getTime();
    long distanceInMin = difference / 60000;

    if ( 0 <= distanceInMin && distanceInMin <= 1 ) {
        return "Less than 1 minute ago";
    } else if ( 1 <= distanceInMin && distanceInMin <= 45 ) {
        return distanceInMin + " minutes ago";
    } else if ( 45 <= distanceInMin && distanceInMin <= 89 ) {
        return "About 1 hour";
    } else if ( 90 <= distanceInMin && distanceInMin <= 1439 ) {
        return "About " + (distanceInMin / 60) + " hours ago";
    } else if ( 1440 <= distanceInMin && distanceInMin <= 2529 ) {
        return "1 day";
    } else if ( 2530 <= distanceInMin && distanceInMin <= 43199 ) {
        return (distanceInMin / 1440) + "days ago";
    } else if ( 43200 <= distanceInMin && distanceInMin <= 86399 ) {
        return "About 1 month ago";
    } else if ( 86400 <= distanceInMin && distanceInMin <= 525599 ) {
        return "About " + (distanceInMin / 43200) + " months ago";
    } else {
        long distanceInYears = distanceInMin / 525600;
        return "About " + distanceInYears + " years ago";
    }
}
```

The problem is that the create_time of the post is 6 hours ahead of my time (EST). So the timeAgoInWords method doesn't work correctly. Does Facebook always record the creation time of posts in UTC/GMT +1 hour?

What can I do to convert the creation time so that timeAgoInWords will work correctly for the current user's timezone, no matter where they are?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the code I use to convert a UTC time string to a localized time string. Note the key for conversion is to use the `TimeZone` methods `getRawOffset()`, `inDaylightTime(...)` and `getDSTSavings()`.

Note my date format is slightly different to what you are using so you'll need to change it.

```
public String GetLocalDateStringFromUTCString(String utcLongDateTime) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String localDateString = null;

    long when = 0;
    try {
        when = dateFormat.parse(utcLongDateTime).getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    localDateString = dateFormat.format(new Date(when + TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset() + (TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(new Date()) ? TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings() : 0)));

    return localDateString;
}
```

Obviously you want a `Date` object so you just need to change this line...

```
localDateString = dateFormat.format(new Date(when + TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset() + (TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(new Date()) ? TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings() : 0)));
```

...to...

```
Date localDate = new Date(when + TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset() + (TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(new Date()) ? TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings() : 0));
```

...then you just need to change the return type of the method and return `localDate`.

Comment: Thanks! That did it for me. I think I was confused because I wasn't even sure if the time Facebook gave me was in UTC time. But I guess it was, thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. To be honest I don't know anything about facebook but it would make sense for any global system to use UTC.

Comment: Why not just add timezone to date pattern and it will convert to your locale timezone? e.g. "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZZZZZ"

Answer (score 1):

```
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("**USER_TIME_ZONE**"));
```

Answer (score 0):

@Squonk code,

```
public String GetLocalDateStringFromUTCString(String utcLongDateTime) {
    SimpleDateFormat fb_dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZZZZZ");

    SimpleDateFormat my_dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");


    String localDateString = null;

    long when = 0;
    try {
        when = fb_dateFormat.parse(utcLongDateTime).getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    localDateString = my_dateFormat.format(new Date(when + TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset() + (TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(new Date()) ? TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings() : 0)));

    return localDateString;
}
```

This convert FB time format into our custom dateformat. tested using Graph api, and its works without any issues.